# order by one or another field, based on most recent

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

If I have a query like this

```
$line_item_status_query = 
"SELECT p.description, 
       p.production_order_id, 
       l.start_user, 
       p.sequence, 
       l.start :: date, 
       l.stop :: date, 
       pr.id, 
       pr.process, 
       pr.process_sequence, 
       pr.caption_in_process, 
       pr.caption_closed, 
       pr.show_to_customer 
FROM   production_order_processes p 
       LEFT JOIN production_order_process_log l 
              ON l.production_order_process_id = p.id 
       LEFT JOIN processes pr 
              ON pr.process_sequence = p.sequence 
WHERE  l.production_order_id = (SELECT id 
                                FROM   production_orders 
                                WHERE 
       sales_order_line_id = '".$sales_order_line_id."') 
ORDER  BY p.sequence";
```

and `l.start :: date` and/or `l.stop :: date` may be null or empty, how can I do an `ORDER BY` so that I can put the returned results in ascending (or descending order) based on whichever date is more recent?

I'd like to replace the order by p.sequence with some conditional logic, but I am out of my depth.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GREATEST()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

```
ORDER BY
  GREATEST(l.start, l.stop)
```

Answer (score 4):

With a case statement

```
 ORDER BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN l.start>l.stop THEN l.start 
    ELSE COALESCE(l.stop, l.start) 
    END
```

edit: This is a generic SQL solution but if your platform supports it, Frank Heikens' GREATEST answer is neater.

Comment: It was too fast though! I'll have to wait 7 minutes to give you the check mark! :)

Comment: I updated your answer to add condition for when both are not null and l.start is before l.stop (second `when`).

Comment: @AleksG which is unnecessary - if l.start is before l.stop, then the COALESCE will return l.stop. Try them side by side - the results are the same

Comment: aha! You're right. I should be more careful analysing what's going on.  My bad.

Comment: Greatest() also works in Oracle, SQL Server and MySQL, it's pretty standard.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Not in SQL Server (which is my main platform)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your phrase *based on whichever date is more recent*.  However you can use `case` in the order by:

```
ORDER BY (case when l.start is null and l.stop is null then null
               when l.start is null then l.stop
               when l.stop is null then l.start
               when l.start > l.stop then l.start
               else l.stop
          end)
```

This will use for sorting:

- `l.start` if `l.stop` is null
- `l.stop` if `l.start` is null
- more recent of the `l.stop` and `l.start` if both are not `null`
- `null` if both are `null`

Comment: That seems to be what podiluska's solution is doing as well. But as I've said, I'm out of my depth. Does his not do this same functionality? Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm sorry, I neglected to clarify the question. Yes, the bullet points you've listed are exactly what I'd like to do.

Comment: @thomas Almost, but not exactly.  podiluska's answer doesn't cater for the case when both dates are not null and `l.stop` is after `l.start`.  I updated his answer to add that condition.